# Seeing 'ESC[8' at the beginning of lines in iTerm2

Tags: bash, shell, iterm2

In iTerm2, I see lines like the following when I `more` a log file:

```
ESC[8Cat scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
ESC[8Cat scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
ESC[8Cat scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
```

Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Those are terminal escape codes for things like colour or formatting – if you use `less -R` instead of `more`, they should be interpreted properly.

Comment: They also really shouldn't be logged in the first place, so whatever produces the logs maybe has a `--no-color` option or similar to not print them.

Comment: I will note that this appears to be the ANSI escape sequence for moving the cursor forward 8 cells, so basically a literal representation of the effects of display a tab character with 8-cell tab stops.